# How to centre text without changing height of border

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, border

```css
body {
  background-color: #660033;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFF033;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 2px dashed #660066;
}

ul>li:first-child {
  border-left: 2px dashed #660066;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge.chrome=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MedievalSharp" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
```

How i can centre  text in ul list without changing height of the right-border ?
When i tried delete height:100% also the height of right-border has changed, and why when i changing the

```
flex:1;
```

to for example

```
flex:2;
```

Nothig is happening. What's the problem with that ?

Comment: I see your text centered, can you specify when or under what conditions the issue appears?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ea3r9ff/)!
I changed the display property, I don't know if it's ok for you. I don't even know if I'm answering your question, I supposed that you wanted to achieve a vertical align:middle, but you didn't specify it! Hope I helped.

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MedievalSharp" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #660033;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFF033;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
  height:100%;
}

ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px dashed #660066;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

ul>li:first-child {
  border-left: 2px dashed #660066;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center text you can make your flex items become a nested flex containers using `display: flex` and add `align-items: center`, also we can replace `text-align: center` with `justify-content: center`.

Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #660033;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFF033;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul > li {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 2px dashed #660066;
  display: flex; /* new */
  align-items: center; /* new */
  justify-content: center; /* new */
}

ul > li:first-child {
  border-left: 2px dashed #660066;
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge.chrome=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MedievalSharp" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
```